# Android Top-level file

Tags: android

Recently I got a problem from nowhere, having an error while testing my android application went into default activity is not defined(first time it worked with invalidate and restart option, then also had to go to file and sync project with gradle file) and in the end to check my buildl.gradle top level file and to see that some value was changed so I thought deleting that file was a good idea and then it will recreate that file, but it didn't and now I can't figure out how to make it work again. Is there any way recreating that file ? At this moment I have only one build.gradle (Module:app) file and build fails with error message: `Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just created another project and copied build.gradle from ProjectName folder of the newly created project to my old project